# Progressive Web Application fullscreen not working

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps

I have created a progressive web application in angular and was trying to make the app full screen by adding below codes in manifest.webmanifest as below

```
  "display": "fullscreen",
  "start_url": "index.html?fullscreen=true"
```

But it is not working as expected. Is there any other fix for this?

Update: Above code is working when I used the install option in browser, which created an icon in homescreen

Comment: Could you please share the complete code? So that we can assist you

Answer (score 0):

To display it fullscreen and remove native control elements, you have to add the display property with the value standalone (fullscreen won't work):

```
// manifest.json
{
  "name": "Example App",
  "display": "standalone",
  "start_url": "/?standalone=true"
}
```

Comment: Above code is working when I used the install option in browser, which created an icon in homescreen